# BaronReplay file format

Tags: c#, php, file, file-format

When playing League of Legends you can record your gameplay using a program called "[BaronReplay](http://ahri.tw/en/)".

I am writing a site (php) which uses those replays, but can't figure out in what format they are saved. I already have LoL-Replay (a different program doing the same thing which had its file in a json format) working. Does anybody know in what format baron replay saves the information? I only care about the match summary (like the amount of kills etc.) , not the match itself.

I uploaded a baronreplay file [here](http://updo.nl/file/0392b87d.lpr). I tried looking at the source code of baronreplay which seems to be hosted on [github](https://github.com/mhuggins/BaronReplaysSrc), but as i don't know C# i have no idea what its doing.

Thanks!

Comment: try unziping it first

Comment: @Dave I suppose you mean unzip the start of the file? Because it does not work if you unzip everything. Do you have any idea where the summary ends and the actual recording starts?

Comment: Everything is stored as JSON inside the .lpr the .lpr seems to be a binary write stream out see this file https://github.com/mhuggins/BaronReplaysSrc/blob/master/BaronReplays/LoLRecord.cs for how he creates the .lpr and more importantly reads the .lpr in on line 983 seems there's different versions for different formats of the .lpr I thought it was perhaps a zipped file holding files inside but its actually a binary.  In php you can probably use fread to read the binary file into a variable then unpack to convert it back to string data (should be json) then you can parse it as usual.

Comment: @Dave this doesn't seem to work. In the file is also some readable text which i wouldn't expect if it was truly zipped. But maybe I'm wrong and you can have readable string in a zip?

Comment: you can have readable strings in zips (usually in headers) but it looks like he's using just plain old binarywriter not a zip.  he creates an object of json data then binary writes that out to the .lpr file with headers and version numbers in it.  I've had a quick bash at reversing the binary write in php but so far had no luck because he's got different objects of different lengths some are longs,shorts, ints etc its very hard for php to know which chunk of binary data should be unpacked using which method unpack by default wants to run on the entire dataset it'll be hard to do what you want